# ReactJS: Uncaught RangeError after setState

Tags: javascript, canvas, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to create a simple drawing application using ReactJS and Flux. However, I came across a bug [Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded] (it's more specifically a ReactJS problem) I've been trying figure out for a while now.  It occurs when I'm trying to do setState() in a component. Below is part of my code to better illustrate my problem.

**DrawingCanvas.react.js**

```
    var React = require('react');
    var MouseInteractionsMixin = require('../utils/MouseInteractionsMixin');
    var StrokeActionCreators = require('../actions/StrokeActionCreators');
    var StrokeStore = require('../stores/StrokeStore');

    function getStateFromStores() {
        return {
            currentStroke: StrokeStore.getCurrentStroke()
        };
    }

    var DrawingCanvas = React.createClass({

        mixins: [MouseInteractionsMixin],

        styles: {
            canvas: {
                border: '1px solid black'
            }
        },

        getInitialState: function() {
            return getStateFromStores();
        },

        componentWillMount: function() {
            StrokeStore.addChangeListener(this._update);
        },

        componentDidMount: function() {
            this._onChange();
        },

        componentDidUpdate: function() {
            this._onChange();
        },

        _onChange: function() {

            if(this.state.dragging) {
                StrokeActionCreators.beginStroke(this.state.mouse.point);
            } else {
                if(this.state.mouse.event == 'mouseup') {
                    StrokeActionCreators.endStroke(this.state.currentStroke);
                }
            }
        },

        _update: function() {
            this.setState(getStateFromStores()); // where the problem occurs
            context = this.getDOMNode().getContext('2d');
            context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
            this._draw(context);
        },

        _draw: function(context) {

            context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            context.lineJoin = 'round';
            context.lineWidth = 5;

            // Draw current stroke (incompleted)
            for(var index = 1; index < this.state.currentStroke.points.length; index++) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(this.state.currentStroke.points[index - 1].x, this.state.currentStroke.points[index - 1].y);
                context.lineTo(this.state.currentStroke.points[index].x, this.state.currentStroke.points[index].y);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }


            /*// Draw the other completed strokes
            for(var strokeIndex = 0; strokeIndex < this.state.strokes.length; strokeIndex++) {
                var stroke = this.state.strokes[strokeIndex];
                for(var currentPointIndex = 1; currentPointIndex < stroke.points.length; currentPointIndex++) {
                    var previousPointIndex = currentPointIndex - 1;
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(stroke.points[previousPointIndex].x, stroke.points[previousPointIndex].y);
                    context.lineTo(stroke.points[currentPointIndex].x, stroke.points[currentPointIndex].y);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.stroke();
                }
            }*/


        },

        render: function() {
            return (
                <canvas style={this.styles.canvas} width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} />
            );
        }
    });

    module.exports = DrawingCanvas;
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is trigger an action when the mouse is clicked and starts moving on the canvas, which sends the mouse position data to the StrokeStore. The StrokeStore stores all the mouse position data, so that eventually the DrawingCanvas component requests for the data (hence the getStateFromStores() function) and draws on the canvas, but when I try to set the state in the _update() function and try drawing on the canvas, there would be a large amount of mouse position data coming in (even after moving the mouse a tiny bit then stopping it) and an error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" would come up.

I've tried not storing the mouse position data as a state of the component, but rather separate variables outside the component which I use inside the component, and it works perfectly fine, so I think it's a problem with the setState().

I'd really like to get it working as states (or any other way so that I can contain the data in the stores).

**EDIT:**

**StrokeStore.js**

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatchers/AppDispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var assign = require('object-assign');

var ActionTypes = AppConstants.ActionTypes;

var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

var _currentStroke = {
    // Points array contains point objects with x and y variables
    points: []
};

// Strokes array contains stroke objects with similar structure to currentStroke
var _strokes = [];

function _addPointToCurrentStroke(point) {
    _currentStroke.points.push(point);
}

function _addStrokeToStrokes(stroke) {
    _strokes.push(stroke);
}

function _clearCurrentStroke() {
    _currentStroke = {
        points: []
    };
}

var StrokeStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    emitChange: function() {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },

    /**
     * @param {function} callback
     */
    addChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    getCurrentStroke: function() {
        return _currentStroke;
    },

    getStrokes: function() {
        return _strokes;
    }

});

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
    var action = payload.action;
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.BEGIN_STROKE:
            _addPointToCurrentStroke(action.point);
            break;
        case ActionTypes.END_STROKE:
            _addStrokeToStrokes(action.stroke);
            _clearCurrentStroke();
            break;
        default:
    }
    StrokeStore.emitChange();
});


module.exports = StrokeStore;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Adding snippets from the StrokeStore or a working JSFiddle would realy help...

Comment: @SaphuA Edited and added my StrokeStore, thanks!

Comment: What's in the call stack when the error happens? `setState` is also async, so it's not necessarily the best match for management of points and real-time feedback, especially when it involves drawing on a canvas. Further, as a canvas is retained, redrawing it constantly shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Not sure if I'm doing it right, but it shows (anonymous function) (extensions::messaging:182) in the call stack on Chrome. If redrawing isn't necessary, what would be a better approach? My goal is to be able to separate the stroke data in the store from the canvas component.

Comment: My question is why use the React state system to control drawing and updates? You can just have local fields in the React class. If you want, you can still use a Store, but for real-time drawing, updates, don't rely on something async.

Comment: @WiredPrairie So what you're saying is that for anything directly related to the canvas, I should just contain the necessary data within the React class of the component rather than using stores?

Comment: No -- I'm saying you could use a store if you want, but don't rely on async behavior for updates/tracking mouse/etc. `setState` is async, and ultimately, all it does it trigger `render`. There's really no reason to do that with a `canvas`.